# Placing the semicolon in the Windows PATH environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Where should the trailing semicolon in the Windows PATH environment variable be placed when adding a new folder?

Is it

- [oldPATH];C:\My Folder
- [oldPATH]C:\My Folder;
- [oldPATH];C:\My Folder;

?

I saw different practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one. At least thats what Windows does on mine, so if Windows does it that way then that will probably be best :)

Answer (score 6):

This is not really a syntax thing, actually. The correct answer here is: *Place the semicolon so the result is a valid `PATH`.*

This usually means one of the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Foo\Bar
set PATH=C:\Foo\Bar;%PATH%
```

because usually `PATH` doesn't end in a semicolon, so you have to add one appropriately to not mangle an existing path in it.

Just look at how `PATH` looks like and consider what you need to do if you add another path. This means you have to add a separator (the semicolon) and the path itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first one:
[oldPATH]; C:\My Folder.

If you want to be sure, you can use the formula:
    "%PATH%;C:\My Folder".

If it is only to execute something in, for example, a BAT script, use: 
    SET PATH "%PATH%;C:\My Folder".
(this one will be working just as a temporal variable)

To add a permanent User Enviroment Variable through command line:
        SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\My Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Your oldPATH may end with semicolon, so when using fourth style [newPath];[OldPath] you don't add double semicolons.

```
path=%cd%;%path%
```

Note that windows doesn't care whether you write commands upper- or lowercase.